# Prevent rerenders with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm implementing `zustand` for global state, but I ran into the same issue when setting up my own global state.

As soon as I attach a component to a simple useStore hook, my component renders twice for every update. This happens despite:

- I don't update any state
- No props are changed
- I wrapped the component in a React.memo() just to be sure
- Nothing in the store (created with zustand) has changed - except for the one change that should trigger one update.

[Here's a Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-mendeleev-kxigl?file=/src/App.js) - a minimal example where you can check the logs - after a reload and after every update, it always logs twice. For people who rather see code without it running:

```
import React from "react";
import create from "zustand";

const useStore = create((set) => ({
  bears: 0,
  increasePopulation: () => set((state) => ({ bears: state.bears + 1 })),
  removeAllBears: () => set({ bears: 0 })
}));

const sessionId = Math.random().toString().slice(2, 7);

const App = React.memo(() => {
  const { bears, increasePopulation } = useStore((state) => state);

  console.log("RENDER Bears", bears, sessionId); // always logs twice
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen.!</h2>
      <button onClick={increasePopulation}>increase</button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default App;
```

Now, I understand that having one extra render is not really a problem, it's just that when my app grows, I tend to have a couple of those components nested into each other, so that when I **do** want to minimise the amount of renders, it becomes hard to know where to start.

**So, my questions are:**

- Why is this happening?
- Can I prevent this double render and if so, how?
- If not, what is the proper way to deal with this?

Comment: did u wrap you app component with React.StrictMode?, if so please try to unwrap it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your app is wrapped in `React.StrictMode`. The react core team says the double render is intentional.

> It's an intentional feature of the StrictMode. This only happens in
> development, and helps find accidental side effects put into the
> render phase. We only do this for components with Hooks because those
> are more likely to accidentally have side effects in the wrong place.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! For future readers: I was using an app created with create-react-app, which seems to be using strict mode for the dev since february 2020 (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8557) - You can remove it from index.tsx / index.js